# Starts comparing from the first number, not the whole number in kotlin

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin, compare

Hello I need to compare 2 numbers and I used >, => but it doesn't compare whole number, it looks for the leftest(left) number and compare
for example the number is 92,236 and i want to compare it with 100,000, it says 92236 is bigger than 100,000 and it is because of the first number which is 9 and the first number of second number that is 1 so it says 100,000 is not bigger than 9236

here what I had done

class IncreaseMoneyFragment : Fragment() {

```
var decide = ""

val increaseEditText = mIncreaseMoneyBinding.increaseEdt.text.toString()  (get value of edit text)
                        val currentPayment = it.payment  (get loanPayment from database)
                        if (increaseEditText > currentPayment) {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, "more", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            val more = "بیشتر"
                            decide = more
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, "less", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            val less = "کمتر"
                            decide = less
                        }
                        builder.setTitle(" مبلغ مورد نظر از مبلغ قسط وام $decide است. ادامه میدهید؟")
```

THANKS FOR HELPING ME :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely comparing strings (text) and not numbers here. That's why it's using the alphabetical order instead of the integer order:

```kotlin
println("92236" > "100000") // true
println(92236 > 100000) // false
```

You probably want to convert your strings into integers instead:

```kotlin
if (increaseEditText.toInt() > currentPayment.toInt()) {
    // ...
}
```

Note that [toInt](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int.html) will crash if the strings are not actual numbers (for instance empty).

You can use [toIntOrNull](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int-or-null.html) if you want more safety. It returns `null` if the string is not a number, so you can simply check for null and deal with this problem separately before comparing.